# Force open blob url inline inside browser with userscript

Tags: pdf, blob, userscripts, content-disposition

I am a user of web applications from government and health care. They force the users to download PDFs. I prefer to view them in the browser first so I can decide whether to save them or not.

So I installed the add-on called "Simple Modify Header" and added the configuration below.

[image: Simple Modify Header Configuration To Force Open Media In Browser With Content-Disposition:inline]

This worked splendidly for years till suddenly a web application defied the override.

I opened the devtools and detected that blobs are used. Because there's no HTTP response the add-on didn't have an effect.

I single-stepped the application and realized that they are downloading the PDF from an OAuth protected backend and encoding the contents in a blob. I didn't manage to get to the point where the blob is opened. It's hidden behind many complicated indirections. Looks like React or Angular with some Redux and I don't have the sources of course, and it's minified and uglified.

How would you write a user script catching the opening of the blob and forcing it inline inside the browser?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this user script:

```js
function handleClick(ev) {
    let downloadAnchors = document.querySelectorAll("[download]")
    for (let anchor of downloadAnchors) {
        anchor.removeAttribute("download")
        anchor.target = "_blank"
        console.info("Disabled forced download here:", anchor)
    }
}

(function() {
    let capture = true
    window.addEventListener("click", handleClick, { capture })
    console.info("Disabling forced downloads the next click")
})();
```

and it works nicely on the forced download demo page https://davidwalsh.name/demo/javascript-download.php:

[image: First step]
[image: Opened a tab with the file instead of downloading]

but not on the health care web application. Probably this web application doesn't use the download attribute to force the download, or there is some Redux magic such that the `<a download>` element is not created in the click handler.

However I think this user script is still nice, so I post it as an answer.

Maybe I will find out something later.